# Finiteness of birational types for targets of algebraic fibrations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. A *fibration* is a surjective map with connected fibers between projective varieties. Is it true that there's a finite number of birational equivalence classes of projective varieties (say, with representatives $Y_1,\ldots, Y_n$) such that if $X\to Y$ is a fibration then $Y$ is birational to some $Y_i$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Jorge already pointed out this is too much to hope for. On the other hand, if you can put some restriction on $Y$, then there are results in this direction.

1. A theorem of Severi implies that if you restrict $Y$ to be a curve of genus at least $2$, then this is true. (Severi's theorem is slightly more general, requiring only that the map is dominant)
2. Severi's theorem was generalized to the case when $Y$ is a surface of general type by Martin-Deschamps and Lewin-Ménégaux (two people :)...
3. ...and it was generalized to arbitrary dimension ($Y$ is still of general type) by Hacon and McKernan. (See Corollary 1.4 of [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-006-0504-1))

Comment: Cool! Thank you for the references

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so. Consider the product of two isogeneous elliptic curves. This surface has infinitely many smooth elliptic fibrations. The basis are all isogeneous but I guess that they belong to infinitely many distinct binational equivalence classes.

Comment: Thank you! Just a question: could you give an argument to show that the isogeny class contains infinitely many birational (=isomorphism, in this case) classes?